# Show rectangular button using the library Floaty

Tags: ios, swift, floating-action-button

I'm using a floating button using the `Floaty` library ([This](https://github.com/kciter/Floaty) one). It does show the floating button also properly like so

[image]

But I want the floating button to be seen something like so...

[image]

Here the yellow button with the title ‘Contribute’ is what I want from Floaty

Comment: What about a normal UI Button?

Comment: if you want to button as per your requirement you need to make changes in your floaty library. means height , width and position

Comment: True @iOSTeam but that’s what I’m not able to figure out…:)

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to set two properties for `Floaty`

```
floaty.buttonImage = UIImage(named: "yourimage") //this will set your image
floaty.paddingX = self.view.frame.width/2 - floaty.frame.width/2 //this will set it to center.
```

Also there is rotation when you click on this button so for that you need to go to `Floaty` class and then search for below lines and comment it.

```
self.plusLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(self.degreesToRadians(self.rotationDegrees), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
self.buttonImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.degreesToRadians(self.rotationDegrees))
```

And

```
self.plusLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(self.degreesToRadians(0), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
self.buttonImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.degreesToRadians(0))
```

Comment: Ok @Dharmesh. I tried it but still the floaty button is showing as circular while I want it rectangular with rounded corners as shown in the 2nd image attached...

Comment: Have you added image like I suggested?

Comment: It should work. Can you share any demo project where you are trying this?

Comment: It is not an oval shaped image. But just the small image to the left of the title 'CONTRIBUTE'. It is actually an oval shaped button I want..